# MapView not working properly inside fragment android

Tags: android, android-mapview

Hi in my application i m displaying one fragment. Inside that fragment I am displaying map. So my code looks like :

```
   <RelativeLayout 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/innerrelativelay"
       android:padding="10dp">

       <TextView
       android:id="@+id/storename" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Store Name:"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       />
       <TextView
       android:id="@+id/storeaddress" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/storename"
       android:text="Store Address:"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       />
   </RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapView" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/innerrelativelay"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and fragment looks like :

```
public class MyAccount extends SherlockFragment {

    MapView map;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    TextView storeName,storeAddress;
    SharedPreferences storeInfo,authenticationInfo;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maplayout, container, false);
        map = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        map.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMap = map.getMap();
        map.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        storeName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.storename);
        storeAddress = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.storeaddress);

        storeInfo = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(CommonSharedPref.QCMERCHANT_STOREID, 0);
        authenticationInfo = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(CommonSharedPref.QCMERCHANT_AUTHENTICATION_INFO, 0);

        storeName.setText(storeName.getText().toString()+storeInfo.getString(CommonSharedPref.QCMERCHANT_STORENAME, ""));
        storeAddress.setText(storeAddress.getText().toString()+storeInfo.getString(CommonSharedPref.QCMERCHANT_ADDRESS1, "")
                +"\n"+storeInfo.getString(CommonSharedPref.QCMERCHANT_ADDRESS1, ""));


        return v;
    }
}
```

It shows me map properly but creating marker, showing current location or move camera at given location not working properly. 
How to do this. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: @nilkash... You are using Google Map V1 which is deprecated. And Now there is Google Map V2 and Google Map V3 API available. SO you have to Go with it...

Comment: Hi piyush thank you for help. I follow this https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551 and I think its map v2.

Comment: means animate camera from current location to new location??

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes. That animate to given location or adding pin is not working.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Try changing the layout of fragment as

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Also it seems you havent initialised the markers yet. Thats why markers arent visible.. 
If you need pointers of how to do it.. There is a very good tutrial page...

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

From here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview, you can see that

> Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API as been officially
>   deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012

So you shouldn't use MapView anymore. I suggest you use a MapFragment instead. See the excellent documentation for it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment

Comment: Augustus Thank you for help . I already check given google example. It uses map activity i want to use fragment. And when I use map fragment in main activity it gives me error when i add that fragment to my main activity. But whats wrong with my code. It run without any error. even it display map as well. But not displaying marker. Am i doing anything wrong. Need help.

Comment: thank you for help again. But fragment inside fragment layout is not allowed. But my question remain unanswered that its not giving error then why it is not accepting that marker and move camera animation things. Thank you.

Comment: 'double latitude = ;
double longitude = ; 
// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");
// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);'

Try this code instead.
Just check if you are getting any errrors in logcat, btw.. Hope this helps.
I couldnt find any other reasons to this. But, if you are interested, I could give another simple map method

Comment: Also you are using 'map.onCreate(savedInstanceState);' twice. delete the second reference. Also try using some other coordiantes as latitude and longitude